# iOS: get result of 'currentUserNotificationSettings' alert dialog

Tags: ios, push-notification

When calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings]` for the first time, the user will be asked to allow push notifications. So the result of this first call is always `UIUserNotificationTypeNone`, because the user did not confirm the dialog yet.

Is there a possibility to detect when the user closes this dialog (pressed *Ok* or *Don't allow*)? I want to use this event to reload the current view as its contents rely on the users choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is call the `registerUserNotificationSettings:` on the `UIApplication` which will make the application check the settings for user notifications and show a confirmation dialog to the user. After checking your request against the user preferences, the app delivers the results to the `application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:` method of the app delegate. The object passed to that method specifies the types of notifications that your app is allowed to use.